# MacOS creating launch agent in a console app not working

Tags: macos, cocoa, launchd, launch-agent

I know how to create a launch agent with a normal application say "myLaunchd" and setting "Application is agent" to "YES" and then copying the "myLaunchd.app" to the main app's `Contens/Library/LoginItems`.

But I need agents, which will be created by some scripts and the main-app's bundle-identifier will be provided through command line arguments.

I tried with a console app, tried using it as launch agent, but it doesn't work expected. I noticed that a normal app keeps running until it is closed (if "Application is agent" is set to "NO"). So to achieve similar effect I forced the console app to run-infinitely using `while(1)`, but no luck.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about an agent _application_ (a background app), or a _launch_ agent (a `launchd` managed background process)?

Comment: @red_menace: agent application as I say "Application is agent = YES" in plist

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. A "user agent" is a process (it can be an application, but could be just a process) that is registered with `launchd` and runs when the user is logged in, independently of your app. Is that what you're trying to accomplish?